# Search unreliable author names

Tags: python

We have scanned thousands of old documents and entered key data into a database. One of the fields is author name.

We need to search for documents by a given author but the exact name might have been entered incorrectly as on many documents the data is handwritten.

I thought of searching for only the first few letters of the surname and then presenting a list for the user to select from. I don't know at this stage how many distinct authors there are, I suspect it will be in the hundreds rather than hundreds of thousands. There will be hundreds of thousands of documents.
Is there a better way? Would an SQL database handle it better?

The software is python, and there will be a list of documents each with an author.

Comment: have a look at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_string_searching

Comment: The regex module here supports fuzzy matching: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex`

Comment: Following these links, I think difflib might do the trick, nice and easy and good enough for my application - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use mongodb where you can set list field with all possible names of author. For example you have handwriten name "black" and you cant recognize what letter in name for example "c" or "e"  and you can set origin name as "black" and add to list of possible names "blaek"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sunburnt](http://blog.timetric.com/2010/02/08/sunburnt-a-python-solr-interface/) which is a Python-Solr library which accesses [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which is built on top of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

An excerpt of what Solr is:

> Solr is the popular, blazing fast open source enterprise search platform from the Apache Lucene project. Its major features include powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted search, dynamic clustering, database integration, rich document (e.g., Word, PDF) handling, and geospatial search. Solr is highly scalable, providing distributed search and index replication, and it powers the search and navigation features of many of the world's largest internet sites.

It will give you all you want for searching documents, including partial hits and potential matches on whatever your search criteria is.

Comment: Yes, I used it at my previous company for doing matching on various criteria including partial address information.

Comment: And how it works with huge volume of db for example about 3Gb or more?

Comment: We were running with about ~120GB worth of data and found it to be quite responsive.